# Robot Framework - DataDriver - Select random data from a row within a .csv

Tags: robotframework, data-driven-tests

I have a spreadsheet with about 3k rows I am trying to select data from (row specific) to enter in data for a form.

Currently my code is repeating the test for all rows in the CSV how can I select data from a random row?

Thanks!

Comment: most likely you need to implement your own custom data reader: https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#custom-datareader-classes

Answer (score -1):

You can easily create your own library in python for reading and writing csv files. Here is a quick example which works with every text style file.

```
class costomLibrary(object):
    def read_specific_line(self, filename, row):
        '''
        This creates a keyword named "Read Specific Line"
        This keyword takes the filename of the file to read and the row 
        wich is to be read.
        '''
        fp = open(filename)
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == row:
                return line
```